# Storing UIActionSheet data into array in CoreData

Tags: core-data, uiactionsheet

I've got an issue that's been bothering me.  I have to store information from a UI Action Sheet in iOS into an array provided in CoreData.  Trouble is, the Action Sheet is in a different function than the one used to store the data.

First: Here's the relevant code for storing the data:

```
(... checking for all fields; working properly)

} 
else
{
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newContact setValue:Salutation.text forKey:@"Salutation"];
    [newContact setValue:FirstName.text forKey:@"FirstName"];
    [newContact setValue:LastName.text forKey:@"LastName"];
    [newContact setValue:CompanyName.text forKey:@"CompanyName"];
    [newContact setValue:EmailAddress.text forKey:@"EmailAddress"];
    [newContact setValue:PhoneNumber.text forKey:@"PhoneNumber"];
    newContact.Disinfector =[NSNumber numberWithBool:yesWasher];
    newContact.Sterilizer =[NSNumber numberWithBool:yesSterilizer];
    newContact.CoffeeMaker =[NSNumber numberWithBool:yesCoffeeMaker];

    Salutation.text = @"";
    FirstName.text = @"";
    LastName.text = @"";
    CompanyName.text = @"";
    EmailAddress.text = @"";
    PhoneNumber.text = @"";
    yesWasher = YES;
    [WasherTog setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    yesSterilizer = YES;
    [SterilizerTog setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    yesCoffeeMaker = YES;
    [CoffeeMakerTog setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Second, here's the code for the Action Sheet and handling the input:

```
- (void)showSalutation:(id)sender
{
UIActionSheet *popUp = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Salutation" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Mr.", @"Mrs.", @"Ms.", @"Dr.", nil];
popUp.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
[popUp showInView:self.view];
[popUp release];
}

- (void)showSalutation:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0) 
{
    Salutation.text = @"Mr.";
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    Salutation.text = @"Mrs.";
}
else if (buttonIndex == 2)
{
    Salutation.text = @"Ms.";
}
else if (buttonIndex == 3)
{
    Salutation.text = @"Dr.";
}
}
```

I feel like I'm making a lot of newbie mistakes, so please forgive me.  I've been learning how to code all weekend and you guys have been my best friend for this stuff.  I just haven't seen this particular issue on the net.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are jsut trying to select a string based on the button index use an instance variable. For example you could declare NSString* yourString in the header and use it as follows:

`if (button.index == 0) {
   yourString = @"Mr."
}`

Just following that pattern should work and you can do whatever you want with yourString from there.